# Problems with Loading an Image for a GUI when the classes are in a package

Tags: java, image, swing, loading, jpanel

I've been programming in Java for a little while now but have never really done much with the swing packages. I am currently designing a GUI for an A.I. call and response program despite the relative complexity (for me at least) of the rest of what I have been doing, this image loading problem, which seemed extremely simple to implement is stumping me.

The below classes work if not in a package, which is what really confuses me. I've tried several different implementation suggestions (one from Head First Java, one from the docs.oracle.com tutorials and another using what http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/45imageicon.html suggests).

```
package CaRII;


import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class P{


public static void main(String [] args){

    P p = new P();
    p.go();

}
public void go(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CaRRI: Call and Response Intelligent Improviser");
    PBackground mainPanel = new PBackground();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

    frame.setSize(800,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

```
package CaRII;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PBackground extends JPanel{

public Image backgroundImage;


public PBackground(){

    backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("CaRIIBackGround.jpg");

}

public PBackground(LayoutManager layout){

    backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("CaRIIBackGround.jpg");

}
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,null);
}
}
```

Like I said the strange thing is that it doesn't display the image if these two classes are in package CaRRI; but if I compile and run them without the package declaration they run fine(albiet the image not loading until the window resizes... but i have seen solutions online for that so I will be able to sort that once I get it loading within the package). I have been writing in XCode and JEdit and the image is stored within the package folder inside source (/src/CaRII/P.java ... /src/CaRII/CaRIIBackGround.jpg), I have also tried storing the image in a resources folder within /src/ and using

```
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/CaRIIBackGround.jpg)).getImage();
```

but that that causes another error when run

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
at CaRII.PBackground.<init>(PBackground.java:19)
at CaRII.P.go(P.java:21)
at CaRII.P.main(P.java:15)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as despite its simplicity this has been stumping me all morning and I have a lot of other classes to write.

Thanks
(Heres the image(im a new user so i cant post images but this is a link to it))
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/cariibackground.jpg

Comment: If you are using Eclipse make sure to "Clean" your project as sometime resources are not copied into the bin directory automatically (from which your app tries to load them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package CaRII;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class P{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                P p = new P();
                p.go();
            }
        });
    }

    public void go(){
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("CaRRI: Call and Response Intelligent Improviser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            PBackground mainPanel = new PBackground();

            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

            //frame.setSize(800,500);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class PBackground extends JPanel{

    public BufferedImage backgroundImage;


    public PBackground() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg189/" + 
            "scaled.php?server=189&filename=cariibackground.jpg&res=medium");
        // You might form that URL using something like..
        //URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/CaRIIBackGround.jpg");

        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(
            backgroundImage.getWidth(),
            backgroundImage.getHeight());
        setPreferredSize(d);
    }

    /*  What was this supposed to achieve?
    public PBackground(LayoutManager layout){
        backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("CaRIIBackGround.jpg");
    }
    */

    // Don't override paint() in a Swing panel!
    //public void paint(Graphics g){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // USE the ImageObserver!
        //g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,null);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the void paint(Graphics g) was only being overridden as the last of the implementations I had seen online had done this, but I have heard similar remarks before about not overriding paint. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Andrew there is still an issue, when I then try to mak the Url /resources/cariibackground.jpg a IllegalArguementException is thrown, ive also tried with my full directory path: /Users/andreafeasey/Desktop/Music Computing 2/src/resources/cariibackground.jpg                              heres the error:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1362)
 at CaRII.PBackground.<init>(P.java:50)
 at CaRII.P.go(P.java:24)
 at CaRII.P$1.run(P.java:15)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:677)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
...

Comment: Is the name `CaRIIBackGround.jpg` or is it `cariibackground.jpg`?  The URL was all lower case, but it seems the one on your file-system (and supposedly on the run-time class-path of the application) uses upper case letters.  For `getResource()` to work, the case must be correct!  Also, do a `System.out.println("url: " + url)` once you have it.  The way it is done at the moment is trying to do too much before sanity checking the result of earlier method calls.  Too confusing.  When in doubt, print out!  If you fix the case and the image is still not found, I'd be pulling apart the Jars to check

Comment: I changed it to cariibackground.jpg first off but to no avail, its no matter as this whole project uses Max Msp as its host (all my other classes are declared and instantiated in a mxj object) so I've built the GUI in max instead (probably should have just done this to start but wanted to see whether it would open a JFrame with a coded GUI when the mxj opens). Anyway long story short I have my GUI working great in max with custom buttons and sliders galore. But thanks for your help and I hope this post (and your answer ) sheds some light on Images in java for others as it did me. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me :
    package CaRII;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class PBackground extends JPanel{

    public Image backgroundImage;


    public PBackground(){
        super();
        initImage();

    }

    private void initImage() {
        backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/cariibackground.jpg")).getImage();
    }

    public PBackground(LayoutManager layout){
        super(layout);
        initImage();

    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

But be carefull I've got the same error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException) than you when I generate my jar file because of Upper case in the image name. You should use only lower case names for your resources if you use windows.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks diodfr but this still throws the same exception and I have changed the image name to the lowercase as you have written in your imageIcon declaration. Also I use mac.

Comment: Are you sure you have put the image in the package resources? You should try to unzip the jar file and check that the image is on the resources directory.

Comment: I Have built my GUI in max msp now: it was the host for all my classes anyway so I don't know why I didn't do this in the first place... Anyway besides that this class no longer exists so I can't test this anymore, I will however be sure to follow the help you have provided next time I am building a GUI in java. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Check this Link out, this has to be your Directory Structure, for placing Images, Do check the code example too. [MY PROJECT](http://www.4shared.com/zip/Ff0gWib7/package.html). I just created this project for you to know, how things need to be, to be accessed, if you doing that manually.

Comment: +1 for sharing, but that site's forced advertising is particularly odious. Is something like [Google Sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sites) available to you?

Comment: @trashgod : Is git hub one such thing. Wanted to start doing that, hadn't touch it yet though. Wish I knew some good site about this thing, just for the same reason, I never posted the code on my site. Do let me know if there is some good site for such things. I will appreciate that :-)

Comment: I've used Google sites and SourceForge, but Google code is a popular choice. I'm still learning git :-)